# tesseract 4 (HEAD-ae53ed6) ignores my config file

Tags: ocr, tesseract

The latest tesseract does not take into account config files.

In tesseract 4, A standard command like `tesseract in.png out.txt digits` may output any characters. In 3.05 it outputs the desired digits-only result. Is there a new way to configure tesseract runs? Also, where can I find a summary of what changes in this major version bump?

Answer (score 1):

It's a new bug introduced in Tesseract 4 alpha: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751